# Memory management for reusing UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uialertview

Lets say I have multiple View controller classes using the same UIAlertView *alertView.  *alertView's delegate is set to a centralized delegate.

I do this because would like to use the .tag to do different things based on it.

The question is every time I invoke an alert view or dismiss it, what do i have to do to prevent a memory leak?

Should I not release every time? Or is this a very bad idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Did any of the provided answers, answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UIAlertView may be "shown" from anywhere in your app.  I have an app that the main UIViewController has a timer that every so often brings up a UIAlertView.  When that timer goes off, even if my main view being shown is from a completely different UIViewController (and thus view) the Alert will come to front.

If you really want to "actively" bring up the UIAlertView from any of your UIViewControllers (lets say based upon a user action), then I would do one of two things.

1) setup my Application Delegate Object with the UIAlertView implemented there, with accessor methods for invoking (showing) the Alert view, and thus freeing it from there also, or

2) Generate a singleton like object with the AlertView implemented there!!!

In either case then you can simply dealloc your UIAlertView once within the dealloc routine you write for either of those placements, and alloc it only once when the object is initialized.

Comment: I did this, and in addition, used the UIALertView's "tag" to let me know which alert view is running.

Answer (score 0):

Just treat it like you would any other object.  If you want to keep it around, assign it to a retained property like: self.myAlert.  You still need to release it like you normally would when creating it.  The retained property will take care of keeping it around for you.

Always keep your retains(alloc's, copy's, etc...) and releases balanced.

Comment: What if the retain count at come point become zero before I try to reuse it again?  That means I would need to do a new alloc, but how would I detect if it has been dealloced?

Comment: It will not become 0 if you have assigned it to a retained property.